# Edit opencart header.tpl

Tags: opencart

I'm trying to edit the header.tpl of an opencart website that uses vqmod - I need to add some more info (text) to each menu link, so basically edit the header file.

I've looked into the vqmod manager and files but I can't seem to get it right.

Unfortunately, whenever I try to edit the header file, the site breaks -I've tried editing the cached vqmod files as well, no luck with that.

Is there a way to reset the vqmod / disable it, then edit the header.tpl and enable vqmod again?
Do I need to install a new theme and start from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

To Disable all vQmod's simply rename the files in `/vqmod/xml/` so that their extensions becom `.xml_` instead of `.xml` - Then delete all the files in the `/vqmod/vqcache/` folder so that no cached files are used and it should work. That said, if you are wanting to add extra text to menu items, why not just edit the `/admin/language/your-language/common/header.php` file's text?